# Recommendation on multi-node hadoop cluster installation

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, cloudera

What would be the best way of installing Hadoop 1.0 (whether it is Apache hadoop or CDH)? CDH seems to have some kind of installation manager but somehow I can't find good information on the Web after a couple of hours of searching. I only found documentation about pseudo mode installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just visit [Cloudera](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/home.html) site. They have both [Cloudera Manager](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/products/cloudera-manager.html) free which is very good point to start and standalone [CDH](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/products/cdh.html) package. They also have complete [set of documentation](http://www.cloudera.com/content/support/en/documentation.html) like installation guide for every version of such products.

Of course I'd recommend Cloudera blog and official Apache Hadoop site dicumentation for better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Apache Hadoop not much issues except that I have to resolve any compatibility issue while using hadoop eco system components such as hive, pig, sqoop etc. 
[Cloudera Manager](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UzQ5_S5agqU) on the other side take care of most of these compatibility issues and kind of provides u a complete package with support.
Hope this helps!